# IIS 7.5 wont load web service javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, iis-7.5, scriptmanager

Im having an issue getting my webservice javascript loaded via a script manager

I register a service using the following code:

```
PageScriptManager.Services.Add(new ServiceReference("~/Services/ClientScriptService.asmx"));
```

which in turn generates an html script block

```
<script src="Services/ClientScriptService.asmx/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This has worked for ages but now I get a 404 error from Services/ClientScriptService.asmx/js when I load the site onto Windows Server 2008 R2 which is running iis 7.5
It works fine on my windows 7 box

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Also worth mentioning, the site's been recently upgraded from .net 3.5 to 4.0

Comment: In iis manager, i change the Managed Pipeline mode of the app pool to integrated and it all started working... but I dont understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iis manager, i changed the Managed Pipeline mode of the app pool to integrated and it all started working... but I dont understand why